# Drop Down In UICollectionview

Tags: ios, xcode5

I have a collection view controller and displaying the data in UICollectionView Cells. However, I would like to filter the data. For that, we want to create two dropdown boxes on top as shown in the following image. If user selects a value from one of the dropdowns..the data being shown in collection view needs to be filtered.

[image]

I am trying to use vppdropdown. However, I am unable to add it to my collection view. Any help in this regard is greatly needed.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't add those drop down view to your collection view, you add it as a sibling subview next to your uicollection view.

So something like:

```
- View Controllers
    - View
        - Drop Down 1
        - Drop Down 2
        - UICollectionView
```

Unless your aim is to make the drop down 1 and drop down 2 scroll with the collection view.

In this case, you can either:

1) Embedded the UICollectionView inside a parent UIScrollView

2) Added a header view for UICollectionView and put the drop down views inside the collectionView's header view.